# Webpack import from /folder/folder.js instead of /folder/index.js

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code

With webpack when I create a index.js in ./blah/ then do `import blah from './blah'` it succesfully gets from index.js

However, my code editor is now FULL of tabs called index.js. And doing a Ctrl+Shift+P to find now has a BUNCH of index.js's

Therefore I have been doing name index.js's the same as the folder name. So `/folder/folder.js`. However if I do this, all my import statements are now:

```
import blah from './blah/blah`
```

Now it's not too verbose for me to just type an extra `/blah`. But I was just wondering, is it possible to make it treat the js file with the same name as the folder as it would index.js?

Comment: I think it is impossible.See the `node.js`'s `module` [doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules).

Comment: Ah ok thanks @wuxiandiejia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution to work around this problem is to create a `package.json` inside of each folder like this:

```
{
   "main":"blah.js"
}
```

Comment: Interesting thanks for sharing! This is much better as it doesn't rely on other dependencies, accepting this one instead.

Answer (score 8):

Github user shaketbaby has made a [webpack plugin](https://github.com/shaketbaby/directory-named-webpack-plugin) which handles imports in a manner the question requested.

First add the following to your webpack config:

```
const DirectoryNamedPlugin = require("directory-named-webpack-plugin");

const config = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    ...
    plugins: [
      new DirectoryNamedPlugin(true)
    ]
  },
  ...
}
export default config
```

Then you can use `import blah from './blah'` in order to resolve the file located at `./blah/blah.js`.

If the first parameter is `true`, the resolver will fall back to the previous behaviour
`blah/index.js` in the event that `blah/blah.js` cannot be found.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer. The other answers above indicate that the mapping is _not_ possible - which is untrue, as this post clearly demonstrates. There are also related packages to accomplish this with `jest` and `babel` resolutions.

Answer (score -1):

Another option:

Inside your folder `folder/`, create the following file `index.js`:

```
import folder from './folder.js';
export default folder;
```

Comment: you can make it one line like this:
`export {default} from './folder'`