# Do not import "index.js" on folder import?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am wondering if it is possible to re-configure the import behavior (looking for index.js) on importing module folders directly. By default, when you assume this module folder structure:

```
/components
    /Button
        /index.js
        /style.scss
    /Checkbox
        /index.js
        /style.scss
```

I can easily import the components like this:

```
import Button from 'components/Button';
import Checkbox from 'components/Checkbox';
```

But when I am working on that components, I will have multiple `index.js` files open in my editor/ide which will lead to confusion very quickly. Same applies for the style files.

What I did now is changing my folder structure to this:

```
/components
    /Button
        /Button.js
        /Button.scss
    /Checkbox
        /Checkbox.js
        /Checkbox.scss
```

Which solved that problem and I can see directly where each opened file belongs to.

However, now my component imports look a bit... verbose:

```
import Button from 'components/Button/Button';
import Checkbox from 'components/Checkbox/Checkbox';
```

Because obviously, webpack/babel would look for an "index.js" when I am importing a folder directly. Now my question is: can I change that behavior somehow? I'd like to tell webpack/babel that it should try to import a file named the same way as the folder as the index file.

You can re-configure directory indexes on every webserver, so I am hoping the same is possible with webpack/babel but googling didnt show anything up so far.

Comment: Sounds more like an editor issue? Sublime for instance starts showing parts of the filepath in the name when you have multiple files with the same name open.

Comment: Its not an editor issue - WebStorm does the same but I still dont like it. But i also would like to get red of the "double" import statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack import from /folder/folder.js instead of /folder/index.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870801/webpack-import-from-folder-folder-js-instead-of-folder-index-js)

Answer (score 1):

I went with the following solution:

In each of my folders, I will create a `index.js` next to the "real" module, that has the follwing content:

```
import module from './Button.js';
export default module;
```

This way I am able to keep my code in `Button.js` but am not required to import `Button/Button` someplace else.

I created a little script which automates the creation of the `index.js` files for me, so I don't have any additional work.